Python's America/New_York time offset showing -04:56
I'm currently using Python 3.9.6 and have this simple code
import datetime
import pytz

est = pytz.timezone('America/New_York')
myDateTime = datetime.datetime(year=2024, month=8, day=15, hour=17, minute=00, tzinfo=est)
print("America/New_York: ", myDateTime.isoformat())
print("UTC:              ", myDateTime.astimezone(pytz.utc).isoformat())

which give the result
America/New_York:  2024-08-15T17:00:00-04:56
UTC:               2024-08-15T21:56:00+00:00

Currently in New York it's Daylight Savings time.  So I expected America/New_York to show time offset of -04:00, but it's showing -4:56.  I'm wondering if anyone has an explanation for this.

Try like this:
import datetime  
import pytz  

est = pytz.timezone('America/New_York')  


    naive_datetime = datetime.datetime(year=2024, month=8, day=15, hour=17, minute=0)  
    
    # Localize it to the Eastern timezone  
    myDateTime = est.localize(naive_datetime)  
    
    print("America/New_York: ", myDateTime.isoformat())  
    print("UTC:              ", myDateTime.astimezone(pytz.utc).isoformat())

When you create a datetime object with the tzinfo parameter like this:
myDateTime = datetime.datetime(year=2024, month=8, day=15, hour=17, minute=0, tzinfo=est)


I do not understand your last paragraph

Interestingly enough, that works.  But I'm wondering why the way I wrote doesn't work.  In any case, thanks for the solution!

@Steven: when using the TZ in the datetime constructor, the datetime object does not exist yet, so the TZ does not know how to correctly localize the datetime. Hence it falls back to the earliest entry in the TZ DB, which is New York LMT (check myDateTime.strfmt('%Z')). LMT for New York was 3 minutes and 58 seconds ahead of Eastern Time until Nov 18th 1883, hence the weird offset:  https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/2017b/northamerica#L330
